# C: Static variable depending on function invocation location

Tags: c, function, scope, static

Is there a way to have a static variable in a C program that not only "remembers" its last value, but also its last function invocation location, and keeps a different value for each invocation location?

I mean that when the function is invoked on multiple occasions in the main function, each invocation creates its own "instance" of the static variable, and it is treated seperatly from the other "instances".

So for example if I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int increment)
{
    static int sa = 10;

    sa += increment;

    printf("increment = %d, sa = %d\n", increment, sa);
}


int main()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        foo(1);
        foo(2);
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
increment = 1, sa = 11
increment = 2, sa = 13
increment = 1, sa = 14
increment = 2, sa = 16
increment = 1, sa = 17
increment = 2, sa = 19
increment = 1, sa = 20
increment = 2, sa = 22
increment = 1, sa = 23
increment = 2, sa = 25
```

However, my desired output would be

```
increment = 1, sa = 11
increment = 2, sa = 12
increment = 1, sa = 12
increment = 2, sa = 14
increment = 1, sa = 13
increment = 2, sa = 16
increment = 1, sa = 14
increment = 2, sa = 18
increment = 1, sa = 15
increment = 2, sa = 20
```

In other words, I would like to have two "instances" of `sa`. One of them is incremented by `1` and the other one is incremented by `2` for every main loop iteration.

If this is not possible, I guess I will have to pass the incremented value from `main()` to `foo()` and back every time (or just increment it in `main()`). Or is there a 3rd way to do it?

Note that I would like to have a solution that works for any number of different function invocation locations.

Edit: Removed mismatch between for-loop iteration count and output line count.

Comment: There is only one instance of that variable in your program. You cannot remember values depending on the caller of the function. As you already guessed, you will have to pass the address of a separate counter variable from each caller.

Comment: I believe there can only be one instance of static variable in a program.

Comment: Each calling function will have to keep its own static variable, and pass a pointer to `foo()`.

Comment: The easiest way to substantially get the behavior you describe would be to define distinct static objects in the calling routine(s) and pass their addresses to the function: `int main(void) { static s1; … foo(&s1, 1); static s2; … foo(&s2, 2); } void foo(int *p, int increment) { *p += increment; }`. If that is not satisfactory, you should expound fully upon the requirements.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Does making it `not static` and making them `static` makes any changes? since pointer is being passed?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is satisfactory, thank you! I was just hoping I could find a shortcut to avoid having `s1` and `s2`. But I know now that it's not possible.

Comment: " each invocation creates its own "instance" of the static variable, and it is treated seperatly from the other "instances"." Have it calculate and return a value to the caller? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @Lundin There is no problem, I was just trying to be lazy. In the actual program, there will be several variables that should behave like `sa` and I was hoping to minimize the number of variables that I have to pass back and forth.

Comment: @Dave Maybe a struct would be suitable then?

Comment: @Lundin Yes, that will be my approach. However, one of the said variables is already a struct, and I haven't worked with structs inside structs so far. But I guess I will learn something new today :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an arbitrary number of counters, a macro can be used to create individual and completely separate counters that will do exactly as you want:

```
#define FOO( increment ) \
do \
{ \
    int localIncrement = ( increment ); \
    static int sa = 10; \
    sa += localIncrement; \
    printf("increment = %d, sa = %d\n", localIncrement, sa); \
} \
while ( 0 )
```

Every invocation would create a separate counter at that point in the code.  And `_Generic` could be used check the type of `increment` and improve robustness.

For multithreaded code, `sa` could be an atomic value and an atomic increment could be used.

Answer (score 4):

Definitions of functions do not depend on where they are called.:)

As for your problem you could use two static variables in the function the following way

```
void foo(int increment)
{
    static int i = 0;

    static int sa1 = 10;
    static int sa2 = 10;

    if ( i == 0 )
    {
        sa1 += increment;
        printf("increment = %d, sa = %d\n", increment, sa1);
    }
    else
    {
        sa2 += increment;
        printf("increment = %d, sa = %d\n", increment, sa2);
    }

    i ^= 1;
}
```

Comment: I think instead of `i`, `increment` should be checked for `1` or `2`. `xor` might be just alternating addition. But I think he wants variable according to increment value

Comment: @JustaNobody If he wants then let he will do as he wants.:) I just demonstrated a possible general  approach.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank you :) This is a nice approach if `foo` is called exactly 2 times. However, I would like to be able to call it `n` times.

Comment: @Dave Do you have tried to insert its definition in your program shown in the question? You should get the expected result.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, I have. As I said, it works nicely if I call `foo` exactly from two locations. If I call it from 1, 3, or any other number of locations, the result is not as desired.

Comment: @Dave You can define a static array. In this case you need to pass through a parameter or through a global variable the number of the place from where the function was called.

Comment: Thank you @VladfromMoscow, that seems like a nice way to do it.